# Hosting is IPv4 only, can I have IPv6 clients?

Tags: windows, hosting, ipv6, ipv4

My hosting is IPv4 only. My question is whether it is possible to allow IPv6 only clients to access my web (running Window Server 2012 R2).

Is this possible using technologies like 6to4 or Teredo or something different that I can just install on my server + create AAAA DNS record and it will work? Or do these technologies require configuration on both ends, so that it won't just work even if setup properly on server side?

Note that I do not mind performance impact due to any kind of tunneling.

Subquestion: And vice versa - is it possible for my server to access other servers via IPv6 after some kind of configuration?

Comment: Transition technologies like 6to4 and Teredo are usually unreliable. It's 2015; hosting services offering IPv6 are easy enough to find these days.

Comment: I know that it is easy to find hosts with IPv6 support, but once you have your server configured and running, changing hosting is very painful. I need just a basic IPv6 functionality there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, very good call. If your [vendor, hardware, software, etc.) don't support IPv6 today, it is time to dump it and get something that works.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When Teredo is done properly it is actually fairly reliable. On some carrier grade NAT infrastructures it is actually the case that using Teredo makes communication more reliable than using just IPv4. However Teredo done properly does imply that you only use Teredo addresses for the client side, putting a Teredo address in an AAAA record is not doing it properly.

Comment: what service running in the server are trying to access by your clients?. Just browse your website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your server is IPv4-only then IPv6-only clients can't access it. One of the sides has to have something that is compatible with the other side. Most IPv6-only networks still have access to IPv4 servers through NAT64, but let's assume they don't (because you don't want to be dependent on some DNS and NAT hacks at the client side). You'll have to make your server reachable over IPv6. In the comments the best solution for that has already been given: kick your hosting provider to make them get their act together, or move to one that already has. Until that has been fixed you can use e.g. Tunnelbroker.net to get IPv6 connectivity to your server.

Comment: https://www.tunnelbroker.net/ is what I was looking for. It is super easy to setup, it just works and my server is now accessible via IPv6 clients and it can also access IPv6 servers acting as client.

Answer (score 0):

There are free IPv6-IPv4 and IPv4-IPv6 gateways online. These are transparent gateway/proxy that will let you access an IPv6-only website from an IPv4-only network and vice versa, such as the SixXS tool at: https://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/

With SixXS gateway, for example, to access serverfault.com from an IPv6-only network just visit http://serverfault.com.sixxs.org
These tools have often limited bandwidth and functionality, e.g. SixXS gw doesn't work with SSL.

To enable IPv6 on your domain without change your hosting provider, you can use reverse proxy services such as Cloudflare, more info on https://www.cloudflare.com/ipv6/